# openstack swift saio unittest error

Tags: unit-testing, openstack

i'm trying to install openstack swift object storage by this link 
http://swift.openstack.org/development_saio.html
on centos  6.5 
i think i did everything correctly, but when i'm trying to run unit test script its showing my these errors,
and i have to say that before this there was a lots of confilicts whit python packages in version number, i had to uninstall some the packages and the reinstall the corresponding version to fix this,

here is the detail when i'm running unit testin on swift

Comment: this is the file that contains the error http://pastebin.ca/3201381

Comment: somebody help me please.